# Maven plugin for versioning and minifying javascript

Tags: javascript, git, build, maven, minify

### Single Page Javascript Application

I have built a sophisticated ajax-driven single page webapp that uses a RESTful backend web service serving JSON. The javascript is split into many different files, each file representing some sort of feature or component.

While the service has been in *alpha* testing, I've just be serving all these files separately without minification. But now that I'd like to launch a *beta* version, I really need to combine files, minify them, and version them. I want to add this to my build process, using Maven.

### Javascript File Types

I'm using the following "types" of javascript files, of which #3 and #4 are my concerns:

1. External files, such a jquery and jquery-ui served from the Google CDN. Rarely change these versions, can be handled manually.
2. Jquery plugins that I'm hosting myself, such as fullcalendar or ui-layout. Again, I rarely update these to new versions and can handle it manually.
3. Application-wide javascript code. Custom javascript that is spread across many files and can change occasionally. All of these files need to be loaded for the app to work.
4. Feature-specific javascript code. Custom javascript that is loaded on demand when a specific feature is requested. This code can change quite frequently and is not loaded at startup.

### Build Objectives

I'd like to do the following during my build process:

- Concatenate all type 3 javascript files together, minify them, and save as a single file with a version number. For instance: `app-2.0.6.min.js`, where 2.0.6 is the maven project version.
- All type 4 files should be individually minified and saved as separate files with version numbers in the name. For instance: `feature-abc-56ab32de29.min.js`, where 56ab32de29 is the version number of that specific file.
- Update HTML files with `<script>` tags to point to javascript files with the correct version numbers.
- Update Javscript files that load type 4 feature javascript files to point to the right versions.

### Questions

- Is there a maven plugin that will assist with the concatenation?
- Is there a maven plugin that will assist with the minification? Ideally, I'd like to use Google Closure Compiler, but would work with others if simpler.
- Is there a maven plugin that will assist with the versioning?
- Is there a way to have the type 4 javascript files have independent version numbers? Ideally, if a file doesn't change between version 2.0.5 and 2.0.6, there is no need for users to download a new version and their cached version would work fine. I'm using GIT for source control, so would there be a way to use a file's GIT hashcode for versioning?
- Is there a solution that will compress the javascript that is inline in regular HTML files without killing the HTML?
- Is there a solution that will compress and version my CSS files as well?

Comment: Have you given the accepted answer a try? How did this all turn out for you? I'm working on a project that is identical to yours in high level architecture (I guess this is a common sense paradigm nowadays).

Comment: @Ates: actually, no. I haven't tried either answer yet. Got busy with other aspects of the project. Hope to get to this sometime soon. If you try them, out, could you post your experiences?

Comment: I found a Rails specific tool that looks to do much of what I want. Of course, it isn't a maven tool, and I'm not using Rails, but it could be worth checking out:  https://github.com/documentcloud/jammit

Comment: @Ates: I have tried yuicompressor-maven-plugin and it works sweetly. It also has a jslint goal which you can use to validate your js files.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Take a look at the [yuicompressor-maven-plugin](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/index.html). It can aggregate various js (as well as css) files as well as minify and obfuscate them.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Any thoughts on versioning the files?

Comment: Use the suffix parameter of the yuicompressor-maven-plugin. For example <suffix>-${version}.</suffix>.

Comment: Hi Tauren, for versioning you could take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856091/updating-jsp-script-tag-during-maven-build-phase

Answer (score 11):

Here's a brand-new Maven plugin that targets this task: http://mojo.codehaus.org/webminifier-maven-plugin/

Comment: Your link is broken. Is there any newer alternative ?

Answer (score 3):

I've successfully incorporated RequireJS optimization (uses Google Closure compiler + does concatenation) in a Maven environment (for single page JS app). See my question and the follow up answer for details: [RequireJS Compilation in Maven project with external JS dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663686/requirejs-compilation-in-maven-project-with-external-js-dependencies)

You could probably expand on that to version and archive the minified JS artifacts.