# RequireJS Compilation in Maven project with external JS dependencies

Tags: dependencies, maven, javascript, requirejs

I have a web project that's built with Maven and I'm trying to figure out the best way to compile the JavaScript files with the RequireJS compiler (this question could apply to any compiler/minifier as well).

I have a setup that works, but it needs improvement:

I've packaged the 3rd party JavaScript libraries and they are being downloaded as dependencies and then added with the WAR Overlay plugin.

I have an Exec plugin task that runs the RequireJS compiler *inside the target* directory. I currently manually run `exec:exec` after the package target runs (and therefore the WAR contents are placed in the target directory).

What I would like instead is to make JS compilation part of main (Java) compilation. The JS compiler itself (Require JS) is downloaded as a dependency during the WAR overlay phase which happens after compilation. So, I need the Require JS files to be downloaded and unpacked and I need to run the JS compilation using those files, before/during/after Java compilation.

I'm sure there could be several ways to achieve this. I'm looking for the most elegant solution.

---

**Update: Existing POM snippets**

I have JavaScript dependencies which I have zipped and added to our repository manager:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.requirejs</groupId>
        <artifactId>requirejs</artifactId>
        <version>0.22.0</version>
        <classifier>repackaged</classifier>
        <type>zip</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jqueryui</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.7</version>
        <classifier>repackaged</classifier>
        <type>zip</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Take note that RequireJS itself (which is required for the compilation of the rest of libraries) is also loaded as an external dependency. So the first thing is, I need this dependency to be downloaded and unzipped before I can commence with RequireJS compilation.

These dependencies are being added to the WAR using the WAR Overlay plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <overlays>
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>org.requirejs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>requirejs</artifactId>
                        <classifier>repackaged</classifier>
                        <type>zip</type>
                        <targetPath>lib</targetPath>
                        <includes>
                            <include>requirejs/require.js</include>
                            <include>requirejs/require/*</include>
                            <include>requirejs/build/**</include>
                        </includes>
                    </overlay>
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>com.jqueryui</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
                        <classifier>repackaged</classifier>
                        <type>zip</type>
                        <targetPath>lib</targetPath>
                    </overlay>
                </overlays>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Even though I don't need `requirejs/build/**` to end up in the WAR, I'm including it as part of the overlay to get the unzipped RequireJS build scripts, simply because I haven't figured out a better way.

Then I have a Exec plugin task that performs the compilation. But note that this task hasn't been added to the normal compilation work flow: I have to manually invoke it with `mvn exec:exec` **after** the WAR packaging is done:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>lib/requirejs/build/build.bat</executable>
                <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}</workingDirectory>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>name=bootstrap</argument>
                    <argument>out=combined.js</argument>
                    <argument>baseUrl=scripts</argument>
                    <argument>optimize=closure</argument>
                    <argument>excludeShallow=plugins/manifest</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

So, some questions are:

1. How can I extract different portions of a single zipped dependency for the compilation and WAR packaging steps? Or do I have to create two zip files, one with just the runtime stuff and the other for compilations scripts?
2. I would like to trigger `exec:exec` ideally during compilation, or if not, just prior to WAR packaging. How do I do that?

I have actually tried a bunch off stuff without success, so I hope I don't appear as lazily posting a huge chunk of code and waiting for answers :) It's just that I haven't quite wrapped my mind around how Maven targets/phases etc. work yet.

Comment: Perhaps you could post the relevant pom snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've come up with the following solution that works for me:

Instead of depending on the WAR overlay for the unpacking of the RequireJS files, I explicitly unpack them using the Dependency plugin:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>unpack</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>org.requirejs</groupId>
              <artifactId>requirejs</artifactId>
              <version>0.22.0</version>
              <type>zip</type>
              <classifier>repackaged</classifier>
              <overWrite>true</overWrite>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

The phase is set to "compile". This allows me to have the entire contents of the RequireJS package under the "dependency" folder, during compilation. So, the next thing I have is:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <executable>
              ${project.build.directory}/dependency/requirejs/build/build.bat</executable>
              <workingDirectory>
              ${basedir}/src/main/webapp</workingDirectory>
              <arguments>
                <argument>name=bootstrap</argument>
                <argument>out=scripts/compiled.js</argument>
                <argument>baseUrl=scripts</argument>
                <argument>optimize=closure</argument>
                <argument>
                excludeShallow=plugins/manifest</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

This triggers RequireJS compilation inside the "dependency" folder, without touching either my source directory or the WAR directory. I then continue using the WAR overlay plugin to cherry pick the RequireJS files that want to go into the WAR.

**Update**

Since writing this solution, I've switched to using the "java" goal instead of "exec" because I had problems with using the RequireJS compiler's shell script + batch file through Hudson. I'm basically running the final Java command (generated by the scripts) that run the compiler through Rhino. The Node solution would be slightly different. For RequireJS 0.23.0, it goes something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compile-js</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <workingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</workingDirectory>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                    <!--argument>${project.build.directory}/dependency/requirejs/build/lib/rhino/js.jar${path.separator}${project.build.directory}/dependency/requirejs/build/lib/closure/compiler.jar</argument -->
                    <argument>${project.build.directory}/dependency/requirejs/build/lib/rhino/js.jar</argument>
                    <argument>org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main</argument>
                    <argument>${project.build.directory}/dependency/requirejs/bin/x.js</argument>
                    <argument>${project.build.directory}/dependency/requirejs/bin/</argument>
                    <argument>${project.build.directory}/dependency/requirejs/build/build.js</argument>
                    <argument>name=bootstrap</argument>
                    <argument>out=scripts/compiled.js</argument>
                    <argument>baseUrl=scripts</argument>
                    <argument>optimize=none</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This tries to run node so I get an error message when executing the compiler. Node shouldn't be a requirement for requirejs compiler, no?

Comment: @adam: This was with RequireJS 0.22.0. Did you try this with 0.23.0? The build scripts are significantly different between the two.

Comment: yeah, i was using 0.23.0, which executes the node command in build.bat or whichever .bat it executes

Answer (score 8):

https://github.com/jakewins/requirejs-maven

Comment: I've moved this into https://github.com/jakewins/brew which adds support for compiling coffeescript and haml templates. The brew plugin has some bugfixes that are not available in requirejs-maven. Brew is still unstable, but is actively developed and used in production.

Answer (score 6):

There's a maven plugin specifically targeted for RequireJS optimization at:

https://github.com/mcheely/requirejs-maven-plugin

It should always ship with a recent version of RequireJS, and it's pretty easy to override that by adding a different version to your project, and specifying it's path in the plugin config.

Full disclosure: I wrote the plugin.

Comment: This works great if the project is standalone but it doesn't seem to work if we pull in things via maven-war-plugin overlay (per OP's question) -- does it?