# Doing r.js minification with webjars

Tags: java, javascript, maven, minify, webjars

Our team is writing a server-client application where the frontend is an Angular.js single page application which uses a Spring MVC java backend. The backend serves the application files and the REST endpoints used by the browser end. We are using Maven as the main build system for the application.

We like to take advantage of require.js and r.js to minify the app at the end, and we are also using client side dependency management. Currently we are using bower to download Javascript libraries required but it doesn't feel right to me to download client dependencies to src/main/webapp since this is a source folder. However in order to avoid rebuilding the whole frontend module each time something changes in the client files, this seems the only sensible way to us. This way we can start a web server and it will automatically pick up changes without restart, but as i said this doesn't fit Maven's folder layout.

I'm experimenting with Webjars which seems a better choice in our Maven oriented build and dependency management. Because in Servlet 3.0 containers webjar resources are provided automatically on the server container path it's very easy to use and manage them. It's also possible to create a require.js config to refer to libraries contained in webjars since they are on the webserver path the same way if they were static files, the serving is being done transparently in the client applications point of view.

My only problem is that i don't know how could we achieve r.js minification with this layout, since the source files are in jar files r.js cannot access them. Also the require.js config refers to the runtime server paths which are simply not there in build time.

I see that [webjars now have some integration with Require.js + Play Framework](http://www.jamesward.com/2014/02/19/official-support-for-requirejs-in-webjars) but we are not using Play just simple Spring MVC in our case. I really hope there is a way to handle this case because i like the Webjar way of client dependency handling.

Answer (score 4):

You need an asset compiler / pipeline in your build process.  There are probably many options but the one I know of is wro4j: http://alexo.github.io/wro4j/

Comment: Thanks, i was not aware of wro4j :) I will try it soon.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not exactly an answer for my question. Wro4j is very nice but currently does not support require.js, browserify or any other client side module management system so you have to hardcode the script order in wro.xml. I'm looking for something which understands require statements in js files and calculates the dependencies based on them and it's also capable of making minification based on this setup during release build.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663686/requirejs-compilation-in-maven-project-with-external-js-dependencies