# Do i have a chance to run a user defined program to generate resource?

Tags: java, maven

I have a `war` project with maven ,

And I wonder if there is a plugin OR such a mechanism to generate resources at compile time so that I can minify `CSS` or minify `JS` or generate CSS-sprite  ?

I think this should be a very nice plugin.

Comment: Not sure about maven, but in Eclipse you certainly can do it. And Eclipse can work with maven.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965801/maven-plugin-for-versioning-and-minifying-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I've not used it myself, but the [invoker plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/examples/post-build-script.html) appears to be what you need. It gives you the ability to run scripts pre and post-build. For your case, just use a pre-build script to run whatever utility you need.