# updating jsp script tag during maven build phase

Tags: java, jsp, maven, maven-plugin

I want to update content inside all script tags in jsp files present under src/main/webapp/jsp.
How to do this during maven build phase?

I am using java+spring+maven stack.

Ok here is example of what I want to achieve:

Source code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"  %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core/validator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/util/core-util.js"></script>
<div id="dataContainer">
</div>
```

After maven build, this should be present in target folder

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"  %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core/validator.js?version='<MD5SUM-of-js/core/validator.js>'"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/util/core-util.js?version='<MD5SUM-of-js/app/util/core-util.js>'"></script>
<div id="dataContainer">
</div>
```

Please note the version parameter at the end of src="".

**Update:** Finally, I was able to make it work following way. Feel free to suggest alternative if any.

1. Prepared shell script to generate properties file something like this

   js/core/validator.js=js/core/validator.js?version\=MD5SUM-of-js/core/validator.js
   js/app/util/core-util.js=js/app/util/core-util.js?version\=MD5SUM-of-js/app/util/core-util.js
2. Configured maven-replacer-plugin to use this properties file as token value map and filter all the jsp files present under target/app/jsp folder.

Comment: voting to reopen - even if the question was originally asking for "tool or plugin", plugins are maven core features as is the filtering of resources. basically OP seems to be asking "how to do this in maven", which is on-topic for SO.

Comment: so can you manually write the md5sum of those files into pom.xml, or do you expect it to be counted on every build? if the latter, the main task is counting it first and getting that into a maven property. that might be tricky.

Comment: I want the latter. I already have one shell script to count md5 of all js and css files in my project.

Comment: maven has plugins to do the same, which would not be environment specific like shell scripts are. but main problem with both plugin and shell script approach is getting the result into a maven property. But thanks for the clarification, I'll update my answer then...

Comment: Thanks eis! I came up with one solution and updated the question. Please take a look.

Comment: well, it's your choice, I personally would've used filtering - but you can add your own solution as an answer and accept that.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't tell what kind of replacement you need, but...

For lot of the cases, you can just use regular maven resources plugin and turn filtering on. That way it will replace any `${values}` with maven runtime properties.

[Documentation about the plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

For .jsps, you are possibly already using war plugin. With war plugin it is something like

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/WEB-INF</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*.jsp</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
            </webResources>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Then you'd have something like this in your JSPs:

```
<script src="${mypath}/test.js"></script>
```

And in maven pom:

```
<properties>
   <mypath>testpath</mypath>
</properties>
```

Depending on your project configuration. (src/main/webapp is often used as well, for example)

---

Edit: you have added in the comments that you have a shell script counting md5 and you want to use that. I don't know an elegant way of doing that, so suggesting a less elegant way: use groovy plugin to execute the script and get the value to a property.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <providerSelection>2.0</providerSelection>
                <properties>
                    <script>path/to/your/shell-script.sh</script>
                </properties>
                <!-- if the script prints its result to stdout -->
                <source>
                    def command = project.properties.script
                    def process = command.execute()
                    process.waitFor()

                    def result = process.in.text.trim()
                    project.properties.md5Value = result
                </source>
                <!-- if the script prints the result to a file -->
                <!-- note that you have to define this result file name somewhere -->
                <source>
                    def command = project.properties.script
                    def process = command.execute()
                    process.waitFor()

                    def resultfile = new File(project.properties.result_file)
                    project.properties.md5Value = resultfile.getText()
                </source>
                <!-- only use one or the other script block! -->
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: `I want to update content inside all script tags in jsp... ` so looks like OP wants to update JSP and it have nothing to do with Maven

Comment: @Karna "during maven build phase", says the subject, or?

Comment: @Karna ... what? Of course it can and filtering of resources is one of its core features

Comment: filtering is different than changing file contents. Isnt it?

Comment: @Karna no, it most certainly is not. What do you think it does? I've used maven filtering for years without issues, and it is pretty much all about changing content of files specified as resources.

Comment: My bad.. Didnt knew that you can define properties and update them at runtime. You got my vote..

Comment: Thanks for replying eis! I have updated the question. Please take a look.

Comment: @TechnoCrat updated answer based on question and your comment about a shell script

Comment: Thanks again! But where is it updating/filtering the jsp files happening?
I don't want to add something like ?version=${property.key.placeholder} because that would require me to change ~300 jsps in the project I am currently working on.

Comment: @TechnoCrat well, that's how filtering works that you add a placeholder like that. It's probably easier to do a search-and-replace once for all .js texts in all jsps with a separate tool first.

Answer (score 1):

if the only thing you want is to add a checksum to your `?version=xxx` and it does not need to be a result of your custom shell script, you can use `maven-antrun-plugin` and its `checksum` target in conjunction with resource filtering.

The JSP snippet:

```xml
<!-- WEB-INF/jsp/template/thePage.jsp -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="${jsDir}/awesomeScript.js?version=${md5.awesomeScript}"></script>
```

Antrun plugin snippet:

```xml
<!-- pom.xml -->
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <phase>validate</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>run</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <target>
        <checksum file="${jsDir}/awesomeScript.js" property="md5.awsomeScript"/>
      </target>
      <exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

And finally the resources plugin snippet:

```xml
<!-- pom.xml -->
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <goals>
      <goal>copy-resources</goal>
    </goals>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <configuration>
      <resources>
        <resource>
          <directory>${project.basedir}/war/WEB-INF/jsp/template</directory>
          <targetPath>${project.basedir}/war/WEB-INF/jsp</targetPath>
          <includes>
            <include>*.jsp</include>
          </includes>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
      </resources>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

The `checksum` target of the `antrun` plugin should calculate the checksum and expose it in the `${md5.awesomeScript}` property.

The `resources` plugin comes in a later phase and copies all the `.jsp` files from the `WEB-INF/jsp/template` folder to the `/jsp` root, filtering the maven properties.

So, you should end up with a jsp file where the `?version=${md5.awesomeScript}` is enhanced with the formerly generated checksum.

The snippets I included are just, well, snippets. You might need to provide some further configuration in order for the code to work.

---

In case you HAVE to calculate the `MD5` in your custom shell script, I'd suggest extending the script so it does the find-replace-copy for you and using the maven `exec` plugin to run it.

---

Hope this helps a little! :-)

Answer (score 1):

can i ask you how you did it at last?
can i did it without "?version=''"
like this

```
source:
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core/validator.js"></script>
after build:
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core/validator.js?version=xxxx"></script>
```